# Issue with portals

Tags: plone

I am using Plone 4 and have some issues with view mode of some files.

In a number of areas, when I look at *contents*, the material I posted is there. When I look at *view*, it is not. I am not sure how to rectify this problem. Your detailed instructions would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: More details would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The View of a folder can be set to display various templates, or a page within the folder. Click on the Display dropdown for the folder, and you will see that the top part is a listing of the different templates that can be used as the view. Each of these should display all of the folder contents, just in different layouts.

The other options is to display a page as the default view.  This allows you to choose a page or collection from within the folder to display when you view the folder, instead of a listing of contents.